# HTTP ERROR 500...is it a server error or problem in the app?

Tags: python, html, flask

```
enter code here
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
results = pickle.load(
open("C:/Users/Faye/Desktop/xxxxxxxx/sentence-transformers/final.pkl", "rb") #is the problem with the pkl file? should the file contain only numbers or can it contain text too? 
)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("search_engine.html") #html code is added and it works fine


@app.route("/predict", methods=["GET", "POST"]) # i have tried both methods get and post and only post
    def predict(): 
    int_features = [float(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
    prediction = results.predict(final_features)

    output = round(prediction[0], 2) #should the prediction part has different numbers?

    return render_template(
    "search_engine.html",
    prediction_text="The best investor for you is: {}".format(output), #this prediction text is part of the html code. 
    )


@app.route("/predict_api", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def predict_api(): #should i add anything here on the api?

    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    prediction = results.predict([np.array(list(data.values()))])

    output = prediction[0]
    return jsonify(output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The HTML code has been tested as a snippet and works fine. I have saved the predictive results of the embeddings as pkl file. I have imported on the app. I am making a semantic search engine with keyword matching but the app does not work. I receive this error 500 internal server error.

Comment: Flask will usually produce a 500 when your application raises an unhandled exception. You shuld be able to see the traceback somewhere o the server.

Comment: Have you looked in the webserver error log?  There should be an error message that says exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Yeap I received that jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound

TemplateNotFound: search_engine.html

Comment: I solved it...the html opens in the server...however when i put the keywords i again have server error.